# Subdomain routing in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, routes

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is something like this

```
@GetMapping("domain.xyz")
public String getHomepage() {
    [...]
    return "homepage/main.html";
}

@GetMapping("something.domain.xyz")
public String getSubdomainHomepage() {
    [...]
    return "homepage/subdomain.html";
}
```

Both **domain.xyz** and **something.domain.xyz** are pointed to the same server and the Spring app then considers the subdomain when routing so I can have different content on the top level domain and different content on the subdomain(s)...

Is this possible to achieve with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

(Note: This is not 100% tested, but will probably work)

I'm assuming you are having an Nginx or Apache in front of your Spring Boot application.

With Nginx for example, you would use the proxy_pass directive and then set the **"Host" header** to your "something.domain.xyz" or "domain.xyz" when forwarding to your Spring Boot app.

You could therefore enhance your GetMappings to **filter for the Host header values**.

```
@GetMapping(value ="/", headers="Host=domain.xyz")
public String getHomepage() {
    [...]
    return "homepage/main.html";
}

@GetMapping(value ="/", headers="Host=something.domain.xyz")
public String getSubdomainHomepage() {
    [...]
    return "homepage/subdomain.html";
}
```